# Can I reduce the size of the openCV library when using only a fraction of the features on a java project?

Tags: java, opencv, build, installation, dependencies

I downloaded openCV to use some dependencies to read frames and am using about 1% of the entire library. I fear that using this library when I actually build the project as an executable would be monumental, but is it possible to pick and choose?

I'm new to the build side of things but don't want to add a 1.2GB library to a very small project when accessing maybe one single DLL.

All I'm importing are these:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;
```

I have the entire thing as a dependency in eclipse just for development but I fear the build woes.